# In perl is it possible to use the same elements created in an array in file.csv and do a foreach on file1csv as well

Tags: perl

In file.csv i have created an array from all the unique values found in column B. now i want to do a foreach on the same values in column C of file1.csv is this possible? I can't hard code the values of the array as they change to frequently and every time the user runs the script there would be errors. so that is why i created the array values like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk;
use Tk::BrowseEntry;
use POSIX 'mktime';
use POSIX 'strftime';
open(STDERR, ">&STDOUT");

   ########  entry widget to get $yyyy $mmm $dd   #######################################

print "\n    Select Year            = $yyyy\n";
print "\n    Select Month       = $mmm\n";
print "\n    Number of Backup Days  = $dd\n";

     ########     create  input and output files    #######################################

my $filerror = "\n\n! Cannot open File below, please check it exists or is not open already?\n"; 
my $OUTFILE = "C:\\Temp\\$yyyy\$mmmAudit.txt";
my $INFILE1 = "c:\\file1.csv";
my $INFILE = "c:\\file.csv";
#Open input file for reading and Output file for writting
open (INPUT,"$INFILE") or die "\n$filerror\$INFILE",,1;
#open (OUTPUT,">$OUTFILE") or die "\n$filerror\n$OUTFILE",,1; 

my $total_names = 0;
$total_names++ while (<INPUT>);
my $Month_total = $total_names * $dd;
     #########   get total number of rows in files   ##################################
print "\n    Total number of names is $total_names\n";
print "\n    Total number of names is $Month_total\n";
close INPUT;
open (INPUT,"$INFILE") or die "\n$filerror\$INFILE",,1;
     #########   keep only unique names to do a foreach in file1.csv#########
my %seen;
while (<INPUT>)
{
    chomp;
    my $line = $_;
    my @elements = split (",", $line);
    my $col_name = $elements[1];
    print "    $col_name  \n" if ! $seen{$col_name}++;
}
## now in file1.csv i want to do a for each on all $col_mames's
close INPUT;
```

Comment: Try rephrasing your question to match your code, or vice versa - there's no file.csv, file1.csv in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... you don't need to loop over the whole file twice - it looks like you're doing it the first time just to count line numbers - could you not do that inside your second loop?  Saves the open/closing too... which for the same file is odd.

Your second file you can loopover just after grabbing each column name unless I'm missing something.  Not efficient code, but it'll do it.